# How can i set Mojo Paramater from the pom.xml of Mojo plugin without project

Tags: maven-plugin, mojo

I write a Mojo Plugin. It has a Pamameter like:

```
*@Mojo(name = "showModus", requiresProject = false, defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_RESOURCES)<br>
public class ShowModus extends AbstractMojo { <br>
@Parameter (property = "modus", defaultValue = "${modus}")<br>
private String modus;*
```

in Pom.xml of Mojo Plugin i define a property for this:

```
<properties><modus>1.1.1</modus></properties>
```

It works fine if i call the Mojo goal direct under project order per mvn

But if i call the mojo plugin direct form maven repo or. in directory without mojo plugin the Parameter modus is not set.

I understand that mvn can not find the pom.xml of mojo plugin project and therefore can not set the value to parameter.

Is there any way where i can set the pom properties of the mojo maven plugin to the generated plugin.xml ?

I wourd like to call (use) the mojo maven plugin direct from maven repo with certain parameter whereby their value set or inject from pom.xml of plugin

Greeting

Answer (score 0):

I don't completly understand why you want to write these values as properties in the `pom.xml`.
It is much easier to write the in a Java constant. But maybe there are some aspects for this decision.

Some basics:

1. You can read and parse a `pom.xml` with the [`MavenXpp3Reader`](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/maven/model/io/xpp3/MavenXpp3Reader.html) (this class is part of the [`maven-model`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/index.html) module)
2. Maven writes the `pom.xml` into the jar at `/META-INF/maven/<groupId>/<artifactId>/pom.xml`
3. the plugin itself is on classpath while executing a maven goal
4. you can access classpath resources by using [`getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-)
5. you can get the Properties by using the method [`getProperties`](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/ModelBase.html#getProperties())

Packing up all these parts it looks something like this:

```
final String pathToPluginPom = "/META-INF/maven/de.example/example-maven-plugin/pom.xml";
try (InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(pathToPluginPom)) {
    final MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
    final Model model = reader.read(stream);
    final Properties properties = model.getProperties();
    final String myPropertyValue = properties.getProperty("myproperty");
    getLog().info("Property: " + myPropertyValue);
} catch (final IOException | XmlPullParserException ex) {
    getLog().error("ERROR!", ex);
}
```